# How to share a method in an ASP.NET core web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a few utility methods I would like to access from various pages in my ASP.NET core web project.  I assume there is a simple way to define the methods once and call from various pages without copying and pasting the utility methods into each page that uses them.

I see recommendations to add a WebAPI project to my solution, but that seems like overkill for a couple of methods.

Is there a simple way to share a method within a project I'm missing?

Comment: You can create a project for example `MyprojectName.Lib`, writing your method and then create package to publish in`Nuget` with specific version. On your main projects, You can install your package whit `NugetPackageManager`

Comment: I usually create a project that is called Common. Inside of it I keep several static classes with several static methods that is reused in the most of my solutions.

Comment: Share example code of what you want to reuse?

Comment: As far as I know, normally, we will create a service inside the asp.net core project and then we could inject this service into the controller or else then we achieve call this method at each service or controller.